# Is it a bad practice for Amazon Cognito to keep the UserPoolId and ClientId hardcoded in the source code on the front end?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, security, amazon-cognito, cloud-security

I would like to ask if there is any security misconfiguration in Amazon Cognito to store the UserPoolId and the ClientId hardcoded in the source code of a web page. Let's say that an unauthorized user can find these IDs in the source code and create a user. Is this a bad practice?

I am interesting to know if this is a security issue. I have tried to research this problem, but I did not find any exact responses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are the Cognito User pool id and Client Id sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47833797/are-the-cognito-user-pool-id-and-client-id-sensitive)

Comment: In the context of OIDC the userPool is your IdP, and ClientId is where specifically the auth attempt comes from (which app/website). So exposing that is about equivalent to exposing info like "mywebsite.com uses google auth for login" - it just establishes that `website` agrees that google has authority on who is authorized, and that google thinks that the requests coming with this ClientId is from `website`. Worst that can happen - somebody can call google pretending to be `website`, but without any secrets that's almost useless (unless you allow signup).